# sorting a pair of vector in c++ by second element and if got same second then sort it according to first

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std, std-pair

Can anyone please explain how it works?

We are not calling `sortbysec` as function, but still I got the right answer.  Why there is no need to pass the pair in `sortbysec`?

Please explain, as I am confused about internal workings of `std::sort` function.

```
bool sortbysec(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b)
{
    if (a.second == b.second)
        return (a.first < b.first);
    else
        return (a.second < b.second);
}

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sortbysec);
```

Comment: `sortbysec` when passed as an argument into `std::sort` passes a function pointer.  The `sort` function calls that function with two values from `v` any time it wants to compare `a < b`.

Comment: Okay I will read more about function pointer to know why there is no need to pass the parameters. Thanks

Comment: Whenever you have a function name on its own, it's a function pointer.  As soon as you add some parentheses to it, it's a function _call_.  These things are very different.  You can pass a function around just like any other value.  That's what's happening here.  The function is not called when you do that.  You are simply telling `std::sort` what function it can use to compare any two values.

Comment: Now got it Thanks so much @paddy :)